# How to show the bootstrap 4 validation feedback using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

What I want to achieve is: Getting the form validation information from server using an ajax call and show the errors/invalid feedback inside `.invalid-feedback` with `:invalid` css applied to the input fields.

```
<form id="register-form" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label class="sr-only" for="first_name">first name</label>
     <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" value="" class="form-control" >
     <div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
  </div>
....other inputs
</form>
```

I was able to set the error messages inside the related `invalid-feedback` using:

```
$.ajax({
            url: actionUrl,
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: 5000,
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                if(response.errors === ''){
                    pageRedirect("register/login");
                } else {
                    $.each(response.errors, function(field, error) {
                        form.find('[name="' + field + '"]').siblings('.invalid-feedback').text(error);
                    });
                    //feedback is set now how to show them??
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented on Bootstrap's Forms documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/):

> **Server side**

> We recommend using client side validation, but in case you require server side, you can indicate invalid and valid form fields with .is-invalid and .is-valid. Note that .invalid-feedback is also supported with these classes.

In short, you need to add the CSS class `is-invalid` to form controls that have validation errors.  When you do this:

- the form control will be surrounded with a red-outline to indicate that it has a validation error
- sibling divs with the `invalid-feedback` CSS class will be rendered as red text

Here's a code snippet illustrating this in action with a "mock" response.  Try click the Validate button:

```js
var form = $("form").first();
    $("#validate").click(function() {
        var mockResponse = {
            errors :
                {
                    'first_name': 'First name must not be blank',
                    'last_name': 'Last name must not be blank'
                }
        };
        $.each(mockResponse.errors, function(fieldName, error) {
            let field = form.find('[name="' + fieldName + '"]');
            field.addClass("is-invalid");
            let immediateSibling = field.next();
            if (immediateSibling.hasClass('invalid-feedback')) {
                immediateSibling.text(error);
            } else {
                field.after("<div class='invalid-feedback'>" + error + "</div>")
            }

        });
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="bg-light">

<div class="container">    
    <form id="register-form" novalidate>        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="first_name">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" value="" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="last_name">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" value="" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <button id="validate" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Validate</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Omair. I just had to change the last line of code to `form.find('[name="' + field + '"]').addClass("is-invalid").siblings('.invalid-feedback').text(error);`

Answer (score 0):

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/#custom-styles

As you can see, the script shown there doesn't use AJAX at all. Form validation on the client side is done entirely on the client side.